# Why i am asking password on git clone?

Tags: linux, macos, git, ssh, https

When i run this on mac, everything is ok :

```
git clone git@test.test-project.com:my_project
```

When i run it at home and copied my home id_rsa.pub key to ssh project in authorized_keys , ssh connection is ok, but **cloning git repo requires password**, why?

Full steps to reproduce:

```
git config --global user.name 'User Surname'
git config --global user.email 'user@email.com'
ls -al ~/.ssh # shows nothing 
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "user@example.com"
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
sudo apt-get install xclip
xclip -sel clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Paste id_rsa.pub from cliboard to github account -> settings ->  ssh keys -> add and press enter, it added successfully

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

Hi user! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
Paste the same id_rsa.pub to evernote

From my working mac, copy it from evernote, and connect to ssh:

```
ssh portal@my-server.com
ee ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Paste id_rsa from evernote in end of file and save file.

```
cd my-rails-app/repo
git ls-remote
```

Copy part of first string from stdout:

> From git@test.test-project.com:my_project

Connect to ssh from home asus

```
ssh portal@my-server.com
```

everything is ok

```
git clone git@test.test-project.com:my_project
```

-> required password

Comment: What are the exact sequence of steps your run?

Comment: I added full steps to reproduce to the main question above

Comment: I had this problem because a program i had installed, changed the `~/.ssh` default location. You can see this by running in `Git Bash` the command `ssh-keygen`.  If your default location is not `/c/Users/<your user name>/.ssh/id_rsa` than you shoud look at `Enviromental variables` to see if some variable is changing `.ssh` location.

Answer (score 3):

When the ssh keys are not configured correctly, then the git clone "git@{host}" tries to connect to {host} as user "git", hence the request for a password. So you'll need to fix/troubleshoot the ssh keys issue.

Do your work/mac/home computers have different user-names? Are you using gitolite, gitlab, etc? How was the ssh.pub configured in git?

Note that if (1) *"when I run this on my mac, everything is ok"*, then (2) *"run it at home and copied my home id-rsa pub key to ssh project in authorized-keys"*,  this doesn't make sense for git. You've only enabled ssh login as "you", not as "git". The easiest solution is to copy your private ssh key "from your mac" and copy it into  your "home" computer's ~/.ssh directory. Otherwise, you just need to add your home computer to your git server's configuration as a new user.

Comment: I think copying my private key is not a good idea. I am using the same  id_rsa.pub for github and working ssh server, does it matter ?

Comment: i added steps to reproduce above, please see it

Comment: @user1028432 _"copying my private key is not a good idea"_ => it's your key, as are both hosts (presumably). But if you don't want to, then create another, separate pub/priv key pair. It seems obvious to me (unless I'm missing something) that if you have: (1) one pub;/priv key-pair; (2) clients "a" (w/ priv key) & "b" (no priv key), & git server "c" (w/ public key); THEN "a" can access "c", but "b" can't -- not unless you copy the private key to host "b". _"I am using the same id_rsa.pub for github and ssh server, does it matter?"_ maybe using separate keys will help sort out the problem.